# How to add "type='text/css'" For CSS In AssetBundle - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using My **AppAsset** Like This Way.

**AppAsset.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
  public $basePath = '@webroot';
  public $baseUrl = '@web';
  public $css = [
    'css/style.css',
  ];
  public $js = [
    'js/myscript.js',

  ];

  public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
  ];
}
```

But, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to see source code,

I get `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`. But, no `type='text/css'`.

How to add `type='text/css'` for all of my CSS?

Comment: Why do you want to? That's the default for links with rel=stylesheet.

Comment: Hi @Quentin : `rel` and `type` is 2 different properties for `<link>`. And, I'm getting `rel` by default. Then, why don't I get `type` property. Because, few design issues are there. Which HTML developer told me because of not having `type`.

Comment: I know the are different. The point is that the `type` attribute is optional, and if you omit it and specify `rel=stylesheet` then browsers will default to `text/css`. Your HTML developer is wrong. Adding a type attribute won't make any difference.

Comment: what about `$cssOptions = array('type'=>'text/css');` .. never used Yii, but it can be found on their Docs

Comment: @moped : Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@Moped** Answered It :

> what about `$cssOptions = array('type'=>'text/css');` .. never used Yii, but it can be found on their Docs

We can use [$cssOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$cssOptions-detail) to add property for CSS.

```
public $css = [
    'css/style.css',
];

public $cssOptions = ['type'=>'text/css'];  

public $js = [
   'js/myscript.js',    
];
```

And, **@Quentin** is too correct:

> The point is that the type attribute is optional, and if you omit it
>   and specify `rel=stylesheet` then browsers will default to `text/css`. 
>   Adding a type attribute won't make any difference.

Because after adding `$cssOptions`, though **link** look like `<link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`. But, it didn't made any difference to CSS.

Comment: you're welcome, this is what I call 55+ points out of the window :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set options for a specific style:

```
public $css = [
    ['css/style.css', 'rel' => 'text/css'],
    ['css/style-2.css', 'rel' => '...'],
    'css/style-3.css',
];
```